# Jquery $.post with json returns no results

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a strange problem, I am performing a simple application process with jquery $ post json, however, nothing is returned, see below how did the codes.:

**application.js:**

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('submit', "form", function() {
        var a = $(this);
        if(jQuery().validate) {
            $('#'+a.attr('id')).validate({
                success: 'valid', submitHandler: function() {
                    $.post(a.attr('action'), $('#'+a.attr('id')).serialize(), function(r) {
                        if(jQuery.ui) {
                            $('#msn').attr('title',r.resp);
                            $('#msn').html(r.msn);
                            $("#msn").dialog({
                                width: 350,
                                height: 135,
                                modal: true
                            }); 
                            $("#msn").dialog("open");
                        } else {
                            alert(r.msn);   
                        }
                    }, 'json');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('ok');  
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('form').submit();
})(jQuery);
```

**controller.php**

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'resp' => 'ok',
    'msn'  => 'registered successfully'
));
```

Comment: are you checking in your browsers developer tools in the network / requests tab?

Comment: are you sure whats in a.attr('action') is a correct and/or correct link where you are sending post to?

Comment: did you check if it is entering into the if loop. try putting a `console.log` statement after `if(jQuery().validate) {` and see if it works

Comment: Hello People, yes, he does post correctly, however, the return is not returning anything. I'm working on localhost and if I remove the 'json' the $.post, it will return, but does not return to a format json

Comment: Using the .complete function: 'json').complete(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
   });

I had the following result on the link (image): http://postimg.org/image/3xp4cuqml/

Comment: One more detail, I am using codeigniter, is that this is a problem in CI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and can not believe the file was in **Unicode signature (BOM)** enabled and that prevented the file correctly return the json.